# Differences between LXDE with Debain and Lubuntu in size and in lightness

Tags: linux, debian, lxde, lubuntu

I read from a website that Debian with LXDE is more lightweight than Lubuntu although lubuntu's size is 1 GB and debian's is 1.9 GB?  How could it be? Is it realy lighter than Lubuntu?  Which one contain more packages?  Does the lightweightness depends on size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lubuntu tweaks LXDE to make it work and look in a somewhat different way compared to 'vanilla' LXDE. Debian-LXDE is much closer to the 'vanilla' LXDE.

Light-weight can mean different things.

- RAM usage: You can define the footprint of a desktop environment by how much RAM it needs to run idle, and how much its default tools need. In this case you can compare `lubuntu-desktop` with `lxde` of Debian. You can use various tools for this task, for example

  ```
  free -m
  top
  htop
  ```
- Size of the iso file or installed system on disk: The size of the installed system is the size of a fresh installed system (before you have added files manually) as reported by for example

  ```
  df -h
  ```
- If the iso file is bigger, there are more packages or bigger packages or both.
- I consider RAM usage the main criterion to decide the footprint or lightweightness of a desktop environment.